# Error List Sorting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, error-list

I am running Visual Studio 2015. I accidentally click on "Sort by line number" in the visual studio error list. Now I have no idea how to get it back to the default sort, sort by order of occurrence.

Can anyone help me with this? I have searched all over for an answer and all I can find is that you can't do it. In that case, would uninstalling and reinstalling visual studio work?

Comment: The columns have *three* sort selections.  Up, down and unsorted.  The first two are indicated with an up and down triangle, the 3rd by a no triangle.  Just keep clicking the column header.

Comment: Right Click On the Error List and Will see a Option `Sort By` select what order you want

Comment: @too_cool: in VS 2015 there is no Option Sort By

Answer (score 11):

If the errors are sorted by a certain column, just click that column heading again once or twice until the arrow disappears to go back to default sorting.